# InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'IDocumentService' while attempting to activate 'DocumentController'

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-web-api

now i'm working on Web api Asp.net core,and i have truble with DI.
when i try to send request to my api, i have this error

[image: Request error]

I use Ninject, and i think that i have trubles with this
GitLab with my project https://gitlab.com/ValeriiDmytryshyn/sharedocument

Maybe problems with Startup file

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<DocumentContext>
            (options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection"]));

        services.AddControllers();
        var mappingConfig = new MapperConfiguration(mc =>
        {
            mc.AddProfile(new AutomapperProfile());
        });

        IMapper mapper = mappingConfig.CreateMapper();
        services.AddSingleton(mapper);

        services.AddMvc();

        NinjectModule ninjectModule = new NinjModule();
        NinjectModule serviceModule = new ServiceModule(Configuration["ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection"]);
        var kernel = new StandardKernel(ninjectModule, serviceModule);
        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new NinjectDependencyResolver(kernel));
    }


    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: ok sorry i'll edit it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you need to register your services for Dependency Injection to resolve your classes.

You must register all your injected classes as either Singleton or Transient. This is an example to try inside the startup.cs

```
services.AddTransient<IDocumentService , DocumentService>();
```

See the documentation for more information
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: i'm not shure what i need to registr i'll read dock but now i tried to do somethink like this and have this exception
https://ibb.co/ZNLVBVZ

Comment: Yessss, thank you, i made
           services.AddTransient<ICommentService, CommentService>();
            services.AddTransient<IDocumentService, DocumentService>();
            services.AddTransient<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
in Startup, and changed UnitOfWork constructor